# django haystack search form cannot find is_vald method

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-haystack

I am using haystack to perform a simple search query against my Person model for all the selected filter attributes. I have decide to try out the Faceted Search Form and created a generic TemplateView `SearchView`.

```
class SearchView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"
    results = EmptySearchQuerySet()
    form_class = FacetedSearchForm
    form = None
    query = ''
    selected_people = None

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        self.query = self.get_query()
        if self.form.is_valid():
            self.results = self.get_results()
        context = self.get_context_data(request, **kwargs)

        if request.is_ajax() or request.GET.get('ajax'):
            self.template_name = 'search/Taleebo/search_results.html'

        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def get_query(self):
        return self.request.GET.get('q')

    def get_results(self):
        return self.form.search()
```

All the routing is working fine but when my `get` method is called it fails at the line

```
self.form.is_valid()
```

with an error that says `NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_valid'`

I am using the default form_class so shouldn't that attribute be defined?

EDIT:

I am trying to now use the provided SearchView by haystack and the is_valid is no longer an issue but i am not getting any records back from 'results'. I changed my urls.py to look like this

```
 url(r'^search/person/', search_view_factory(
    view_class=SearchView,
    template='index.html',
    form_class=ModelSearchForm
), name='haystack_search'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using any class would result in the same error, when you don't have an instance to access:

```
class SearchView(TemplateView):
(...)
      form = None  //<= Here you set the form to None
```

So you're calling `is_valid()` on `None`, instead of on an actual form.

Comment: do i have to extend haystack.SearchForm and make my own when the field i am using is the ['q'] query field. What do i specify there

Comment: Most importantly, you should remove that line containing the `None` initialization. Why don't you use the `FacetedSearchView` that is described in the documentation: http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views_and_forms.html#creating-your-own-view ?

Comment: I didn't know such a view existed, in my urls.py file i have specified to use this custom SearchView not knowing that haystack provides one, if everything is set up properly should i just be able to iterate through the 'results' and grab the data i need ?

Comment: Also using this view raises the error ''FacetedSearchView' object has no attribute 'status_code'